# mvc azure ad token expiration

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, token

I'm currently building a mvc5 app hosted on azure which will be in term used throught a WPF app.

As I need to check user group membership I implemented graph API by following the guidance in this article : https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/

It works quite fine but some time after the user logged in the access to the following controller raise an access denied error :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        string uID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
        IUser adUser = client.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId == uID).ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.SingleOrDefault();

        IList<Group> groupMembership = new List<Group>();

        var userFetcher = (IUserFetcher)adUser;

        IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = await userFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync();
        do
        {
            List<IDirectoryObject> directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
            foreach (IDirectoryObject directoryObject in directoryObjects)
            {
                if (directoryObject is Group)
                {
                    var group = directoryObject as Group;
                    groupMembership.Add(group);
                }
            }
            pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
        } while (pagedCollection != null);

        ViewBag.User = adUser.UserPrincipalName;
        ViewBag.UserDN = adUser.DisplayName;
        ViewBag.UserGN = adUser.GivenName;
        ViewBag.UserMail = adUser.Mail;
        ViewBag.UserSN = adUser.Surname;

        return View(groupMembership);
    }
```

The exception is raised on GetActiveDirectoryClient(), the code of this method is a strict copy/paste from the article in the link and looks like this :

```
internal class AuthenticationHelper
{
    public static string token;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Async task to acquire token for Application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Async Token for application.</returns>
    public static async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsync()
    {
        if (token == null || token.IsEmpty())
        {
            throw new Exception("Authorization Required. ");
        }
        return token;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get Active Directory Client for Application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>ActiveDirectoryClient for Application.</returns>
    public static ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClient()
    {
        Uri baseServiceUri = new Uri(Constants.ResourceUrl);
        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient =
            new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(baseServiceUri, Constants.TenantId), async () => await AcquireTokenAsync());
        return activeDirectoryClient;

    }
}
```

This code works perfectly right after the user has logged in but after some times the token become null and so the exception is raised.

I'm guessing this is related to some expiration time, so is there's a way to set some auto refresh on the token ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have `[Authorize]` in your controller, like right before the controller class?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering, I don't have yet set the [Authorize] tag as I would like to as Azure AD group membership to grant access to controllers and haven't yet figured out how to achieve it :)

It seems that appliying mofifications to the authenticationHelper solved the issue :

```
public static ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClient()
    {
        Uri baseServiceUri = new Uri(Constants.ResourceUrl);
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(baseServiceUri, Constants.TenantId), async () =>
        {
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphUrl, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

            return result.AccessToken;
        });

        return activeDirectoryClient;

    }
```

I don't know if that's a clean way to do thing it at least it works.